# SP2013 to SP2016 Migration issue:1 site(s) using SharePoint 2010 experience

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, content-migration

During the SP2013 to SP2016 migration using database attach method, getting below error while mounting 1 Database.

> Mount-SPContentDatabase : Content database data integrity check has encountered a severe issue that upgrade process
> must be stopped. See the upgrade log for more information about how to resolve this issue.
> At line:1 char:1

- Mount-SPContentDatabase
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...ContentDatabase:SPCmdletMountContentDatabase) [Mount-SPC
  ontentDatabase], SPUpgradeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMountContentDatabase
  ```

Error message in log file,

> *1 site(s) using SharePoint 2010 experience.*

It is showing **0 Sites after mounting** but DB contains site 10 collections.
Using below comments all site collections are displaying in PowerShell **but compatibility level field is empty** for all sites collections.

*Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase "Content_DB" -Limit ALL*

All other database upgraded without any issue.
Commands used:

> **Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name Content_DB -WebApplication "http://servername:12345/"**

> **Upgrade-SPContentDatabase**

Tried below solutions from google, but no luck.

1. Results from below query contains 15.0 version above only.

> *SELECT als.id, als.PlatformVersion, aw.Title, aw.FullUrl, aw.ProductVersion, als.Deleted FROM dbo.AllSites als
> INNER JOIN dbo.AllWebs aw   ON aw.Id = als.RootWebId*

2. *Unmounted and re run the SP2016 Configuration wizard. It ran successfully.*
3. 

> $db = get-spcontentdatabase -Identity Id
> $db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()

4. Tried below script to upgrade Sites:

> $webApps = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "http://servername:12345/"
> $sites = $webApps.Sites>
> foreach($site in $sites)
> {
> Upgrade-SPSite -Identity $site -VersionUpgrade -Unthrottled
> $site.Dispose()
> }

5. Tried move site collections to another Db which is mounted successfully. But again version difference
   issue occurred.

Move-SPSite "http://servername:12345/sites/abc" -DestinationDatabase

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Might be time consuming, but try to backup one site collection at a time and restore it to a new site in a single content database in the 2013 environment and then move it to the 2016 environment. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Yes. Actually tried that also. But here also, version difference issue occurred. So, was not able to restore the site in SP2016.  Restore-SPSite : Version string portion was too short or too long